# Console Logs and Alerts not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, gulp, alert

For some reason `console.log` and `alert()` functions don't seem to be working across any of my js files.

I'm using gulp to concatenate and compile a set of .js files (`gulpfile.js` below). I think this is where the problem lies as when I throw an alert or a console.log into an HTML page, they work fine.

```
// include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp'); 


// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Plugins
// ---------------------------------------------------------------

var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var stripDebug = require('gulp-strip-debug');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var include = require('gulp-include');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
//var notify = require('gulp-notify');
//var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// JS
// ---------------------------------------------------------------

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src(['./js/script.js'])
        .pipe(include())
        .pipe(concat('script-dist.js'))
        .pipe(stripDebug())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Sass
// ---------------------------------------------------------------

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('./ui/scss/styles.scss')
        .pipe(include())
        .pipe(sass({
            errLogToConsole: true
        }))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./ui/css/'))
        .pipe(livereload());

        //.pipe(plumber({errorHandler: notify.onError("Error: <%= error.message     %>")}))
        //.pipe(through(function () {
        //    this.emit("error", new Error("Something happened: Error message!"))
        //}));
});


// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Watch & Reload
// ---------------------------------------------------------------

gulp.task('watch', function() {

    gulp.watch('./ui/scss/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch(['./js/*.js', '!./js/vendor/**', '!./js/script-dist.js'],    ['scripts']);

});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'watch']);
gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'watch']);

livereload.listen();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it, it was `gulp-strip-debug`. It strips out all alerts and console.logs.

Commented that out and everything works fine.